# C++ Google Tests and Visual Studio Linker Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I am trying to write tests using the google test framework for a C++ project of mine in Visual Studio.

Here is my current project structure:

```
solution
|
+-- project
|   |
|   +-- src
|       |
|       +-- .testee.cpp
|
+-- test_project
|    |
|    +-- testee_tester.cpp
|
+-- x64
    |
    +-- Debug (standard debug output folder for a generic c++ solution, I haven't changed this)
        |
        +-- testee.obj (files output by compiler and used by linker)
```

Here how I set up the `test_project`:

First the `test_project`  has the `project` as a reference so the build order is: first `project` then `test_project`.

Second here are the `test project` properties:

```
VC++ Directories -> Include Directories: $(SolutionDir)project\src\;$(IncludePath)
VC++ Directories -> Library Directories: $(OutDir);$(LibraryPath)

C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories: $(SolutionDir)project\src\;
%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);

Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories: $(OutDir); %(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);
Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies: testee; %(AdditionalDependencies)
```

I have changed the names of the files and directories to make them easier to read and understand without more context so:

```
solution = sim-world
project = green-sim
test_project = green-sim-test

testee.cpp = spherical-tensor.cpp
testee_tester = test.cpp (temporary name until I get this figured out)
```

And yet when building:

```
Build started at 3:29 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: green-sim-test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'spherical-tensor.obj'
1>Done building project "green-sim-test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 3:29 PM and took 00.381 seconds ==========
```

So the project builds correctly, but the test_project is unable to build because it can't find the .obj file of the testee.cpp file.

I have followed the official Microsoft tutorials for setting these up but I can't quite figure it out.

Here are the tutorials I'm using:

[Write unit tests for C/C++ in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2022)

[Use the Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++ in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2022#object_files)

[Use Google Test for C++ in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2022)

Am I not setting up the project properties correctly?

Why is the linker not finding the .obj file that does exist (I've checked the folder).

Thank you! I hope the question is nice and clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake:
The solution actually has two types of outputs, therefore my understanding of the solution file architecture was wrong:

**Solution Output**

```
solution-directory\x64\Debug\
```

this is equivalent to `$(OutDir)`
which contains the final executables such as `project-name.exe`

and:
**Project Output**

```
solution-directory\project-directory\x64\Debug\
```

which contains all the compiled source code waiting to be linked together such as: `main.obj`

Therefore the linker was searching the wrong folder.
Tada, there is always a simple explanation.

**Conclusion**

In the `test_project` properties:

```
Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories
```

Make sure you add the **Project Output** ie: `$(SolutionDir)project\src\;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it to change its status to Answered. Just a reminder :)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with both Google Test and MS Test frameworks so, to me at least, the problem is in my testing project setup.  I understand the two distinct paths.  Could you please clarify which path(s) you added to which configuration fields in your project config to solve your problem?

Comment: @SimpleCoder Added the clarification! Let me know if you like it

Comment: @ClementFaisandier, thanks for the update.  I'm still having problems getting the test frameworks to see the functions I want to test but I'll figure it out.